# triple integral and cyclindrical coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Find the volume of the region cut from the cylinder $x^2+y^2=4$ by the plane $z=0$ and the plane $x+z=3$.

I know that I will use polar coordinates, however I wonder how to graph it. $z=0$ means $xy$-plane. I cannot solve type of these questions. Is there any person who teaches or helps me? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using cylindrical coordinates the bounds for the integral will be $\theta:[0,2\pi],\;\; r:[0,2]$ and $z:[0,3-r\cos{\theta}]$ Therefore constructing the integral with Jacobian$=r$ we have $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{2}\int_0^{3-r\cos{\theta}}r \; dzdrd\theta$$ I myself am pretty new to volume integrals, but evaluating this expression is how I would do it.
Here is a visual representation of your volume :) Beware that the picture is different at different orientations, here the $z$ axis is vertical, the $x$ axis horizontal and the $y$ axis out of the page towards us.

[image: Here is a visual representation of your volume :)]

Comment: You cannot separate the integrals like this if you have limits of one axis depending on the other.  Atleast it is not a common way of presenting.

Comment: This is the way I was taught to present it, I'm not separating the integrals however. I'll edit to clear up the notation

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

Using Cylindrical Coordinates, $z = z, x = rcos\theta, y = rsin\theta$.

The limits for z runs from 0 at the bottom of the cylinder to a plane 3-x.  Now substitute the expression of x in cylindrical cooridates you get upper limit of z to be $3-rcos\theta$.

Now in cylindrical coordinates $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.  In your equation you have mentioned the cylinder to be $x^2+y^2 = 2^2$.  So limits for r runs from 0 in the centre to 2 at the outer extreme.  Now the you want the volume of the cylinder, so $\theta$ should run from 0 and make one complete revolution and that is $2\pi$.  Thus the limits are from 0 to $2\pi$

Evaluate the the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} \int_{0}^{3-rcost\theta} r dz dr d\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} (3-rcos\theta) rdrd\theta$$

$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} [(\frac{3r^2}{2} - \frac{r^3cos\theta}{3})|2,0] d\theta$$

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}[6-\frac{8}{3}cos\theta]d\theta$$

$$ [6 - \frac{8}{3} sin\theta|2\pi,0]$$

$$ [12\pi - 0]$$

$$ 12\pi$$

Comment: i don't want fish, i want to catch fish, so how is it solved?

Comment: What? We were presuming that you can calculate normal integrals. Normally on this site people offer hints rather than full solutions.

Comment: Really thank you for your correct answers,however wolfram or other website has already given the answer. I just wonder steps of the solution.

Comment: You just evaluate each integral in turn. i.e. integrate with respect to $z$ first, sub in the limits and then proceed with the integral with respect to $r$ and so on.

Comment: messieurs, you don't understand me :) how did you get 3-rcostheta how r=2 and how theta between 0 2pi. I'm sorry I couldn't express myself.

Comment: $x=r\cos{\theta}, y=r\sin{\theta}, z=z$ is the coordinate change for cylindrical coordinates. Therefore we have $x^2+y^2=4=r^2$ and so $r$ is from $0$ to $2$. Since the cylinder is a full rotation around the $z$ axis we have $\theta$ is from $0$ to $2\pi$. Now rearrange $z+x=3$ to find $z$ and sub in $x=r\cos{\theta}$ and since $z$ is also bounded by $z=0$ we have $z$ is from $0$ to $3-r\cos{\theta}$. And the Jacobian for cylindrical coordinates is $r$.

Comment: @George1811,  Nice and concise explanation.  Only other way to explain to this OP is to draw the cylinder show the planes z = o and z= 3-x cut the cylinder for him to view how the cut solid would be.  Good Thanks.  If you have time and resource (some 3D graphing software), insert the image.  That is how we can complete his understanding. I will vote for your concise answer.

Comment: I've included a visual :)